# How to set margin for inner controls of WrapPanel

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Here is an example that I'm using:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextElement.FontSize="30" TextElement.FontStyle="Italic"  >
        <Button Content="test1" Margin="10,0" Padding="10,10" />
        <Button Content="test2" Margin="10,0" Padding="10,10" />
        <Button Content="test3" Margin="10,0" Padding="10,10" />
        <Button Content="test4" Margin="10,0" Padding="10,10" />
        <Button Content="test5" Margin="10,0" Padding="10,10" />
    </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

As you can see, my wrap panel has several buttons.
Each button has the same margin and padding.

The question is, is there a way of setting margin and padding for wrap panel, so each element inside the wrap panel may use it values?

For setting inner element's font, i may use "TextElement" attached property provider. Is there similar way how i can set margin and padding for inner controls?

This make the code shorter and let me specify Margin and Padding only one time instead of setting it for each control in the panel.

Thank you!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[The solution provided by James Hay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656717/how-to-set-margin-for-inner-controls-of-wrappanel/4656785#4656785) is the easiest way to achieve your desired result.

However, there are other possible solutions:

1. You could implement your own attached property/behavior for a `WrapPanel` which sets the `Margin` and/or `Padding` for all its children. See [this CodeProject article by Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx) for details.
2. You could create your own panel which inherits from `WrapPanel` and just adds the required properties and overrides the appropriate methods, so that the `Margin`/`Padding` is set for all child elements.
3. You could also move the `Style` definition from the `Window.Resources` to the `WrapPanel.Resources`, remove the `x:Key` attribute from the `Style`, and remove the `Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"` from all `Button`s. This way, the `Style` is applied to *all* `Button`s which are children of the `WrapPanel`. If you also have other controls as children, you could change the `TargetType` for the `Style` to an appropriate common base type (e.g. `FrameworkElement`):

```
<StackPanel>
  <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <WrapPanel.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,10" />
      </Style>
    </WrapPanel.Resources>

    <Button Content="test1" />
    <Button Content="test2" />
    <Button Content="test3" />
    <Button Content="test4" />
    <Button Content="test5" />
  </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Note, however, that this will influence *all* `Button` instances within the `WrapPanel`, not only its direct children!

Comment: Taking this (#3) one step further - if you want to set the Style on all elements in the WrapPanel, remove the TargetType declaration, and change the Setter to include "Control." for the Property.  For example: <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="10,0" />

Comment: If I do that VS complains that all items in a dictionary must have a key, and if I add the key the style isn't applied to anything.

Comment: The #3th solution seems the more elegant/simple for me and I like it very much! Unfortunately that doesn't work if you have your custom button style set, like this: <Button Style="{StaticResource buttonMainStyle}" ... Am I missing something? Any thoughts?

Comment: That is the expected behavior because WPF always takes the property value that is "closest" to the element in question. That means, since you apply a style on the element itself, WPF does not consider the style that is set in some `Resources` section some levels higher in the tree. I would go with one of the other approaches. There is an example for option #1 in [the answer of Elad Katz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6170172/273527).

Answer (score 17):

Another nice approach can be seen here:
[http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eladkatz/archive/2011/05/29/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-set-spacing-between-items-in-stackpanel.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20120308232328/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eladkatz/archive/2011/05/29/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-set-spacing-between-items-in-stackpanel.aspx)

It shows how to create an attached behavior, so that syntax like this would work:

```
<StackPanel local:MarginSetter.Margin="5">
   <TextBox Text="hello" />
   <Button Content="hello" />
   <Button Content="hello" />
</StackPanel>
```

This is the easiest & fastest way to set Margin to several children of a panel, even if they are not of the same type. (I.e. Buttons, TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, etc.)

Comment: Really nice, I'm going to use it. I'm not a WPF expert but I feel there must be a way to style everything to have a margin without using code that gets executed on runtime.

Comment: Worked a charm, and simple to setup (note you need code behind, which can be found by visiting the link above), +1 for this method.

Comment: The link to your blog seems to be broken. Can you update it or even better copy the contents here?

Answer (score 9):

WrapPanel does not have any properties that add padding or margins to all its children. What you probably want is a style that is share by each button. Something like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,10" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
      <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
         <Button Content="test1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Content="test2" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Content="test3" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Content="test4" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
         <Button Content="test5" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
       </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
   </Window>
```

Comment: Its not really what i need. I just updated an example and added using of TextElement.FontSize and TextElement.FontStyle properties. I need the similar way but for setting margin and padding. Is there any ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a customized WrapPanel control that adds an ItemMargin dependency property.

```
/// <summary>
/// A wrap panel which can apply a margin to each child item.
/// </summary>
public class ItemMarginWrapPanel : WrapPanel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ItemMargin static DP.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemMarginProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ItemMargin",
        typeof( Thickness ),
        typeof( ItemMarginWrapPanel ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            new Thickness(),
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure ) );

    /// <summary>
    /// The margin that will be applied to each Item in the wrap panel.
    /// </summary>
    public Thickness ItemMargin
    {
        get
        {
            return (Thickness)GetValue( ItemMarginProperty );
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue( ItemMarginProperty, value );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overridden. Sets item margins before calling base implementation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="constraint"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override Size MeasureOverride( Size constraint )
    {
        RefreshItemMargin();

        return base.MeasureOverride( constraint );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overridden. Sets item margins before calling base implementation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="finalSize"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride( Size finalSize )
    {
        RefreshItemMargin();

        return base.ArrangeOverride( finalSize );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Refresh the child item margins.
    /// </summary>
    private void RefreshItemMargin()
    {
        var children = InternalChildren;
        for( int i = 0, count = children.Count; i < count; i++ )
        {
            var ele = children[i] as FrameworkElement;
            if( null != ele )
                ele.Margin = ItemMargin;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can just do:

```
<Style
    x:Key="MarginWrapPanelStyle"
    TargetType="{x:Type mycustomcontrols:ItemMarginWrapPanel}">
    <Setter
        Property="ItemMargin"
        Value="5" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score -1):

In case there are not many items in the panel, you could use a Line control and give it a width in case of WrapPanel and height in case of StackPanel. Then you could style the Line.

```
   <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
     <Button Content="test1" />
     <Line Width="15" />
     <Button Content="test2" />
     <Line Width="15" />
     <Button Content="test3" />
   </WrapPanel>
```